# How can I control my Azpen Android Tablet with a broken screen without root or usb debugging?

Tags: rooting, usb-debugging, touchscreen, remote-control, broken-screen

I've had this Azpen A700 tablet for a while, but at some point it got the touchscreen broken. I can still see an image but the touchscreen is completely unresponsive. I'd like to still get some use out of it, but it is not rooted and it has USB debugging disabled. Is there any way to control it or root it without the touch interface? I have a USB cable for it, it's just that the USB debugging setting is turned off.

I've tried googling how to control an android tablet with a usb cable and it requires rooting. Then I looked up how to root a device and it requires usb debugging. Is it possible to do it without rooting or debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get a USB-OTG cable, which allows you to connect USB devices to Android devices via the USB port (so long as the Android device supports OTG, which the A700 does). If you plug in a mouse you'll get a mouse cursor to work with; you could even use a USB hub to attach both a keyboard and a mouse if you want to type instead of using the on-screen keyboard.

You could also use the USB-OTG cable long enough to pair a Bluetooth mouse/keyboard to the tablet, then go wireless.

Comment: Interesting idea. I didn't know that was possible on android tablets. Is it possible to make one of these cables? I have a USB extension cable and a few USB charger cables, so I assume I could simply cut the ends off of both and rewire them to fit. Is this possible or would there be issues? (other than the obvious connecting the wrong wires together) I ask this because I don't have enough money to buy one of these cables at the moment.

Comment: @user1193112 Yes, you can [make one yourself](http://forums.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-7-2012-accessories/200856-diy-making-your-own-otg-cable-image-heavy.html). Most USB controllers have OTG support at the hardware level; as long as the device manufacturer includes software support for the desired peripherals it can work.