# Access files on phone with broken screen

Tags: broken-screen, motorola

I spent a night in the desert in Jordan and the next morning my phone was all wet and the screen went black. That was a few days ago, I'm home now and have bought a new phone (same one). I disabled Google Drive backup and want to access my numbers and photos and whatsapp messages and a couple of other things onto my new phone.

I spent a good two hours googling this question and found some good tips, none of which have worked so far.

- My phone is a Motorola Moto X 2nd Gen
- I can't see anything on the phone except for a 2mm  purple(ish) bit on the top
- I can turn the phone on (doesn't have screen-lock) and blindly click around. I managed to play a song on spotify for example yesterday
- I can also turn on the torch or the camera by shaking or twisting the phone
- I don't have USB debugging enabled
- when I plug in my phone onto my PC, the device shows up but is empty, even when the phone is unlocked

Does it help to buy a OTG (USB) to try to access my phone that way? (for exmaple to turn on wifi)
Or does it help to try to somehow enable USB debugging to try this: 
http://lifehacker.com/android-control-lets-you-use-your-handset-even-with-a-1594719124

**Note:** I've already checked with several questions from the [broken-screen tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info):

- [How to backup broken screen phone when USB debugging IS NOT enabled?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/67352/16575) requires *Samsung Kies* (so it's not an option for a *Moto G*)
- [How can I control my Azpen Android Tablet with a broken screen without root or usb debugging?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/85662/16575) is a good idea if the screen still works, however, my screen is completely black
- [Broken screen while debug mode was disabled. How can I re-enable adb?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/12834/16575) sounds kinda promising but I have no idea how to start my phone in fastboot mode or how to get a recovery system running

I'm not very tech-savy so please go easy on me.

Cheers for any help!!

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! You've picked the right tags already, but might have missed their associated wikis: May I suggest you starting at our [broken-screen tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info), which holds some first-aid plus links to common issues and their solutions?

Comment: Thanks for the link, I don't have KIES (its for Samsung) and can't enable USB debugging.... I could try to blindy enable it but apart from that I dont see a good solution

Comment: You've seen the links to [How to backup broken screen phone when USB debugging IS NOT enabled?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/67352/16575) / [How can I control my Azpen Android Tablet with a broken screen without root or usb debugging?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/85662/16575) / [Broken screen while debug mode was disabled. How can I re-enable adb?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/12834/16575) Didn't any of those get you started? What did you try, where did it fail?

Comment: Hi Izzy, the first Link requires the volume button or KIES which doesnt work since my phone isn't from Samsung. The second link is a good idea if the screen still works, however, my screen is completely black. The 3rd Link (http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12834/broken-screen-while-debug-mode-was-disabled-how-can-i-re-enable-adb) sounds kinda promising but I have no idea how to start my phone in fastboot mode or how to get a recovery system running. If you could help me with that that'd be grand!

Comment: I've integrated those facts directly with your question (to make them easier to spot). As for getting fastboot running: same game, check the [fastboot tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/fastboot/info) for a starter :) Big pointer: Always check the tag-wikis first (and mention if you did and what you've tried from there). They often have good details to get you started :)

Comment: cheers Izzy, so basically I need to download ADB and then I should be able to use adb reboot bootloader to start the phone in fastboot and somehow get a recovery system running. Ill try that at home.

Comment: As for ADB: Make sure to read the … [adb tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info) (there we go again :) Will save you some headache and resources (you won't need to install the full Android SDK as it's often said, for example – a hand-full of files are completely sufficient).

Comment: The adb command needs the phone to be in USB debugging mode. Have you tried the Motorola [Phone Tools](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/prod_answer_detail/a_id/13034) desktop application - it can backup some data from your phone. Or [this](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/78556)?

Moto X has stock recovery which may have backup data option - entering [stock recovery on MotoX](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/prod_answer_detail/a_id/105537/p/30%2C6720%2C9197/kw/recovery).

Comment: Thanks pbhj! I didn't know these tools will defo check them out. Especially since adb is useless since I don't have usb debugging enabled!